# Installing dependencies from DEBs in current directory

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, gdebi

When building a DEB from source, I can use `gdebi` to install the resulting DEB file and also the relevant dependencies from the regular repositories. But sometimes, the dependencies come from other packages or even from the same one and hence can't be found in the repository. For example, the `lyx` source package builds both the `lyx` deb and `lyx-common` which is a dependency for `lyx`. The solution is to first manually install the new `lyx-common` package and then the `lyx` package. However, if more dependencies are involved, this becomes cumbersome.

Is there a way to instruct `gdebi`, or use a different tool, to also look for dependencies in a local directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install all DEB files at once. Open a terminal and run  (Certainly you have to replace the filenames with the correct names.) e.g.:

```
sudo dpkg -i lyx-common.deb lyx.deb
```

or

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

to install really all files at once.

Comment: The reason I tried with `gdebi` is because `gdebi` will resolve dependencies from the repositories. Wouldn't I need to handle dependencies not in the same directory (those which I didn't cread deb files for) manually?

Comment: No, `gdebi` can only install packages, which are available for the package manager, but no additional deb packages in the same folder or in another folder.